# JA017: Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, hue

How can I solve this problem when I submit a mapreduce job in Oozie Editor in Hue? :

JA017: Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID [job_local152843681_0009] which was associated with action [0000009-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-f660]. Failing this action!

**UPDATE:**

```
Here are log file:
2015-07-15 04:54:40,304  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[myserver] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@:start:] Start action [0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2015-07-15 04:54:40,321  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[myserver] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@:start:] [***0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2015-07-15 04:54:40,325  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[myserver] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@:start:] [***0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2015-07-15 04:54:40,501  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[myserver] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@:start:] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@:start:
2015-07-15 04:54:40,502  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[myserver] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W
2015-07-15 04:54:40,713  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[myserver] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9] Start action [0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2015-07-15 04:54:43,216  WARN MapReduceActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[myserver] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9] Exception in check(). Message[JA017: Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID [job_local1099179300_0010] which was associated with  action [0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9].  Failing this action!]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA017: Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID [job_local1099179300_0010] which was associated with  action [0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9].  Failing this action!
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.check(JavaActionExecutor.java:1359)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1288)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:64)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:286)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:321)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-07-15 04:54:43,230  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[myserver] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9] Error starting action [mapreduce-52d9]. ErrorType [FAILED], ErrorCode [JA017], Message [JA017: Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID [job_local1099179300_0010] which was associated with  action [0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9].  Failing this action!]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA017: Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID [job_local1099179300_0010] which was associated with  action [0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9].  Failing this action!
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.check(JavaActionExecutor.java:1359)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1288)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:64)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:286)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:321)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-07-15 04:54:43,234  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[myserver] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9] Failing Job due to failed action [mapreduce-52d9]
2015-07-15 04:54:43,247  WARN LiteWorkflowInstance:523 - SERVER[myserver] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9] Workflow Failed. Failing node [mapreduce-52d9]
2015-07-15 04:54:43,548  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[myserver] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9
2015-07-15 04:54:43,615  INFO KillXCommand:520 - SERVER[myserver] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[] STARTED WorkflowKillXCommand for jobId=0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W
2015-07-15 04:54:43,758  INFO CallbackServlet:520 - SERVER[myserver] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9] callback for action [0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9]
2015-07-15 04:54:43,782  INFO KillXCommand:520 - SERVER[myserver] USER[root] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[] ENDED WorkflowKillXCommand for jobId=0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W
2015-07-15 04:54:43,791  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[myserver] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W
2015-07-15 04:54:43,789 ERROR CompletedActionXCommand:517 - SERVER[myserver] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[-] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9] XException, 
org.apache.oozie.command.CommandException: E0800: Action it is not running its in [FAILED] state, action [0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9]
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.CompletedActionXCommand.eagerVerifyPrecondition(CompletedActionXCommand.java:92)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:257)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-07-15 04:54:43,803  WARN CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper:523 - SERVER[myserver] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[-] JOB[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W] ACTION[0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9] exception callable [callback], E0800: Action it is not running its in [FAILED] state, action [0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9]
org.apache.oozie.command.CommandException: E0800: Action it is not running its in [FAILED] state, action [0000010-150711083342968-oozie-root-W@mapreduce-52d9]
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.CompletedActionXCommand.eagerVerifyPrecondition(CompletedActionXCommand.java:92)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:257)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Did you look at the MR job logs job_local152843681_0009 for more info?

Comment: @Romain I have edited the question with the log file.

Comment: Is YARN configured properly? Did you run some sample MR jobs?

Comment: @Romain Yes, I have added mapred.job.tracker.http.address in mapred-site.xml and yarn-site.xml is empty.

Comment: For me solution was: `hdfs dfs -chown -R mapred:hadoop /user/history && hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /user/history/done_intermediate/hue`

Comment: In addition to prudenko's command, I also had to execute 
   `sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user/history` because this directory had a permission set of 770.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved the exactly same issue. Oozie runs the job by default as "mapreduce". In my case, Oozie couldn't reach hdfs directory /user/history/done_intermediate/hdfs and failed.

So, I bet you were logged as some other login. Switch to mapred login, or add line with

```
user.name=mapred
```

to job.properties if you want to call Oozie from command line.

Comment: Solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426691/oozie-workflow-failed-due-to-error-ja017/44695231#44695231