# Oozie and Job History Server configuration problems

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh, hue

## Problem

I'm trying to install psuedo-distributed [CDH](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_qs_yarn_pseudo.html) without the use of CDM. Everything "works" via the console. However, the second I begin using Hue, I receive an error when trying to work with Pig.

The error shown in Hue is:

> JA017: Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID
>   [job_local2125047777_0001] which was associated with action
>   [0000000-160112011607704-oozie-oozi-W@pig]. Failing this action!

I believe this is an error that is originating due to a miscommunication due to an Oozie workflow issue of connecting Pig with the Job History Server.

Prior to this, I was unable to use Hive from Hue because Oozie had difficulty installing the sharelib for Oozie on HDFS. I resolved this by creating a symbolic link between `/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml` and `/etc/oozie/conf/hadoop-conf/core-site.xml`.  As suggested here: [Apache Oozie failed loading ShareLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702100/apache-oozie-failed-loading-sharelib)

## Script information

The configuration script that I've written to install CDH onto Scientific Linux 7 is available here: https://github.com/coatless/stat490uiuc/blob/master/install_scripts/cdh_build.sh

Specifically, I am trying to obtain results from the pig script:

```
data = LOAD '/user/hue/pig/examples/data/midsummer.txt' as (text:CHARARRAY);

upper_case = FOREACH data GENERATE org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.UPPER(text);

STORE upper_case INTO '$output' ;
```

## Attempted Solutions

From googling, I've come across the following solutions that, once implemented, have not worked out.

- [JA017: Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379961/ja017-could-not-lookup-launched-hadoop-job-id)

Suggested to run the following commands:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/history
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod -R 1777 /user/history
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown mapred:hadoop /user/history
```

Rebooted the Resource & Node Manager, HDFS, and History Server to no avail.

In the thread, there was another user who suggested to set a property in `job.properties` that specified the `user.name=mapred`. However, I could not find any reference to job.properties for Hue jobs.

- [Oozie logs report Unknown hadoop job and history server UI not populated](https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/202530283-Oozie-logs-report-Unknown-hadoop-job-and-history-server-UI-not-populated)

This posts suggests declaring fixed paths for the history server within the `mapred-site.xml` file:

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir</name>
  <value>/user/history/done</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir</name>
   <value>/user/history/done_intermediate</value>
</property>
```

This also did not work.

- [JA017: Unknown hadoop job](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/JA017-Unknown-hadoop-job/td-p/13122)

Indicates the issue may be related to a permissions problem, however, the user does not provide specifics on the how the problem was resolved.

Any help would be appreciated.

## Full oozie log

Full error text from the oozie.log file:

```
2016-01-11 23:51:59,195  WARN ParameterVerifier:523 - SERVER[server-name] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] The application does not define formal parameters in its XML definition
2016-01-11 23:51:59,275  WARN LiteWorkflowAppService:523 - SERVER[server-name] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] libpath [hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/_cloudera_-oozie-1-1452577913.73/lib] does not exist
2016-01-11 23:51:59,572  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[server-name] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[pig-app-hue-script] JOB[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-01-11 23:51:59,595  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[server-name] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[pig-app-hue-script] JOB[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2016-01-11 23:51:59,596  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[server-name] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[pig-app-hue-script] JOB[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2016-01-11 23:52:00,052  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[server-name] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[pig-app-hue-script] JOB[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig] Start action [0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-01-11 23:52:03,487  WARN Credentials:96 - SERVER[server-name] Null token ignored for oozie mr token
2016-01-11 23:52:03,506  WARN Credentials:96 - SERVER[server-name] Null token ignored for oozie mr token
2016-01-11 23:52:03,562  WARN JobResourceUploader:64 - SERVER[server-name] Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2016-01-11 23:52:03,563  WARN JobResourceUploader:171 - SERVER[server-name] No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2016-01-11 23:52:04,169  WARN MRApps:582 - SERVER[server-name] cache file (mapreduce.job.cache.files) hdfs://localhost:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20160111222734/pig/json-simple-1.1.jar conflicts with cache file (mapreduce.job.cache.files) hdfs://localhost:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20160111222734/oozie/json-simple-1.1.jar This will be an error in Hadoop 2.0
2016-01-11 23:52:08,611  WARN Credentials:96 - SERVER[server-name] Null token ignored for oozie mr token
2016-01-11 23:52:08,618  WARN PigActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[server-name] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[pig-app-hue-script] JOB[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig] Exception in check(). Message[JA017: Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID [job_local1961106749_0001] which was associated with  action [0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig].  Failing this action!]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA017: Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID [job_local1961106749_0001] which was associated with  action [0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig].  Failing this action!
       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.check(JavaActionExecutor.java:1274)
       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1203)
       at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:250)
       at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:64)
       at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:286)
       at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:321)
       at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:250)
       at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-01-11 23:52:08,620  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[server-name] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[pig-app-hue-script] JOB[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig] Error starting action [pig]. ErrorType [FAILED], ErrorCode [JA017], Message [JA017: Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID [job_local1961106749_0001] which was associated with  action [0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig].  Failing this action!]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA017: Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID [job_local1961106749_0001] which was associated with  action [0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig].  Failing this action!
       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.check(JavaActionExecutor.java:1274)
       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1203)
       at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:250)
       at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:64)
       at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:286)
       at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:321)
       at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:250)
       at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-01-11 23:52:08,621  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[server-name] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[pig-app-hue-script] JOB[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig] Failing Job due to failed action [pig]
2016-01-11 23:52:08,623  WARN LiteWorkflowInstance:523 - SERVER[server-name] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[pig-app-hue-script] JOB[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig] Workflow Failed. Failing node [pig]
2016-01-11 23:52:08,768  INFO KillXCommand:520 - SERVER[server-name] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[pig-app-hue-script] JOB[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] STARTED WorkflowKillXCommand for jobId=0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W
2016-01-11 23:52:08,806  INFO KillXCommand:520 - SERVER[server-name] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[pig-app-hue-script] JOB[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] ENDED WorkflowKillXCommand for jobId=0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W
2016-01-11 23:52:09,038  INFO CallbackServlet:520 - SERVER[server-name] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig] callback for action [0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig]
2016-01-11 23:52:09,072 ERROR CompletedActionXCommand:517 - SERVER[server-name] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[-] JOB[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig] XException,
org.apache.oozie.command.CommandException: E0800: Action it is not running its in [FAILED] state, action [0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig]
       at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.CompletedActionXCommand.eagerVerifyPrecondition(CompletedActionXCommand.java:92)
       at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:257)
       at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-01-11 23:52:09,082  WARN CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper:523 - SERVER[server-name] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[-] JOB[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig] exception callable [callback], E0800: Action it is not running its in [FAILED] state, action [0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig]
org.apache.oozie.command.CommandException: E0800: Action it is not running its in [FAILED] state, action [0000000-160111235108256-oozie-oozi-W@pig]
       at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.CompletedActionXCommand.eagerVerifyPrecondition(CompletedActionXCommand.java:92)
       at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:257)
       at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Hey how did you resolved this? I am getting same error. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You should doublecheck using the HUE File browser whether all permissions are correct on ALL directories and subdirectories of /user/history.

In my case, all users had permissions on all subfolders of /user/history, but the HUE File browser told me that the '/user/history' directory itself  had the following permission set:

```
Name        User     Group     Permissions
history     mapred   hadoop    drwxrwx---
```

This resulted in the error when using a different user than mapred.
The following command helped:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user/history
```

Comment: Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426691/oozie-workflow-failed-due-to-error-ja017/44695231#44695231

Comment: No idea how often this would solve the problem, but it definitely won't hurt to check this so will upvote :)