# Oozie Workflow failed due to error JA017

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop, oozie

I am using the version of **Apache Oozie 4.3.0** along with **Hadoop 2.7.3**

I have developed a very simple Oozie workflow, which simply has a sqoop action to export system events to a MySQL table.

```
<workflow-app name="WorkflowWithSqoopAction" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
    <start to="sqoopAction"/>
        <action name="sqoopAction">
                <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
                        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                        <command>export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/airawat --username devUser --password myPwd --table eventsgranularreport  --direct --enclosed-by '\"' --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/eventsgranularreport </command>
                </sqoop>
                <ok to="end"/>
                <error to="killJob"/>
        </action>
    <kill name="killJob">
            <message>"Killed job due to error: ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}"</message>
        </kill>
    <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

I have the application deployed in HDFS as follows:

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /oozieProject | awk '{ print $8 }'

/oozieProject/workflowSqoopAction
/oozieProject/workflowSqoopAction/README.md
/oozieProject/workflowSqoopAction/job.properties
/oozieProject/workflowSqoopAction/workflow.xml

hdfs dfs -ls -d /oozieProject

drwxr-xr-x   - sergio supergroup          0 2017-04-15 14:08 /oozieProject
```

I have included the following configuration in the **job.properties**:

```
#*****************************
# job.properties
#*****************************

nameNode=hdfs://localhost:9000
jobTracker=localhost:8032
queueName=default

mapreduce.job.user.name=sergio
user.name=sergio
oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/oozieProject/share/lib
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes=true

oozieProjectRoot=${nameNode}/oozieProject
appPath=${oozieProjectRoot}/workflowSqoopAction
oozie.wf.application.path=${appPath}
```

I then send the job to the Oozie server and start executing it:

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config /home/sergio/git/hadoop_samples/hadoop_examples/src/main/java/org/sanchez/sergio/hadoop_examples/oozie/workflowSqoopAction/job.properties -submit

oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -start 0000001-170415112256550-oozie-serg-W
```

Soon after in the web console of Oozie it is seen that work failed:

[image]

The following error message appears in the sqoopAction:

```
JA017: Could not lookup launched hadoop Job ID [job_local245204272_0008] which was associated with  action [0000001-170415112256550-oozie-serg-W@sqoopAction].  Failing this action!
```

Can anyone guide me about this error?

Running demons:

```
jps

2576 
6130 ResourceManager
3267 DataNode
10102 JobHistoryServer
3129 NameNode
24650 Jps
6270 NodeManager
3470 SecondaryNameNode
4190 Bootstrap
```

Comment: Wild guess: YARN failed to start the AppMaster container for the job, because of a config issue (e.g. Class Not Found), so the job never really "launched", and when Oozie polls YARN for job status it gets no satisfactory answer. Check in the YARN UI what happened to `application_local245204272_0008` *(yes, the "job" prefix is a legacy from Hadoop 1, it is still used by the legacy HistoryServer and by Oozie, but YARN uses "application" prefix)*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, very well argued. I have accessed the ResourceManager Web UI and when doing the "rerun" or sending a new workflow nothing appears ("No data available in table").  No container is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing few configuration properties in hadoop. I was also using hadoop-2.7.3 and Oozie-4.3 and faced same issue from last 5 days.

Configure few properties as mentioned and its working on my local:

yarn-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
    <value>HOST:PORT</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address</name>
    <value>HOST:PORT</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.tasktracker.report.address</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1:0</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.tasktracker.http.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50060</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.queuename</name>
    <value>default</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name> mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>

<property> 
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
    <value>localhost:10020</value> 
</property>

<property> 
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
    <value>localhost:19888</value> 
</property>
```

Replace value of the properties with the actual one as per your setup. Now Restart yarn, hadoop and Oozie.

Good luck.

Comment: Make sure your JHS is up and running.